# How do operating systems determine where to direct device input?

Tags: io, operating-system

Let me give some concrete context for motivation.

I've been enjoying the program AHK for quite some time. It allows the user to script various tasks on a Windows machine and, if need be, bind those actions to hotkeys.

I've never understood how it is that if I create a binding for say `alt+k`, Windows will then understand to first inform AHK when that key-combination is pressed. And if AHK then decides to create the keystroke `down` in response, Windows will know the intended target for that command.

Furthermore, if I start a program in administrator mode, it seems that AHK now no longer gets to preempt any device input. Now the input is immediately passed to the currently focused program. That's unless I also run the AHK script in administrator mode, in which case everything is back to normal.

Can anybody shed some light on what's going on behind the scenes here? And if there are considerable differences on Linux, I'm also interested to hear about those.

Comment: Unless you now what AHK does, this question cannot be understood.

Comment: Aren't you basically asking me to answer my own question here?

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are asking an operating system question or a question about something called AHK.

Comment: I'm asking about operating systems and motivating that question with AHK. How does the operating system know where to direct keyboard input? (Why does it send `alt+k` to AHK and not to the browser that is currently focused?). And how does the operating system know where to send emulated input originating from programs? (Why does Windows send the `down` that AHK outputs to the browser?)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding Operating Systems course, I will answer this in most **Generic way**.

Every **I/O** device has a **device controller**. The Operating System never communicates with the device controller directly. The OS uses a special software called **device driver**(usually provided by the vendor themselves) which sits between the device controller and the OS.

The device driver understands the device controller and provides the OS with a uniform interface to communicate with the device. For example: to start an I/O operation the device driver will load the appropriate registers in the device controller. The controller will examine the contents of the register and examine what action is to be taken(like read a character from keyboard). The controller will initiate the transfer from device to a local buffer.

Once the transfer is complete , it will inform the driver using an interrupt. The driver will return the control back to the operating system possibly returning pointer to data. For other operations driver returns the status.

Comment: I'm not so much interested in how devices communicate to the operating system. I'm interested in how the operating system passes on input to various programs. How does the OS decide who gets what?